# How come there's an argument type function(any) is not assignable to parameter type with React Hook Use State

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, webstorm

I've tried to follow to online tutorial on how to update a state when using React Hooks. Somehow the code is working but the IDE (WebStorm) is complaining about it.

Essentially, what I am trying to accomplish is to only update one of the variables inside the object that I define in the `useState`. Oh, I am using JavaScript and not TypeScript.

For example:

```js
const[test, setTest] = useState({isvalid:false, isCommon:false});
...
function validate(){
   setTest((prevState) =>({...prevState, isValid:true}))
}
```

In the IDE I am getting:

> Argument type function(any) & {isValid: boolean} is not assignable to parameter type...

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code snippet. Are you *actually* using Typescript? Is this just a static code analyzer in the IDE? Seems like it may just be a warning.

Comment: I am using javascript, not sure why the IDE complains about it. But you are right, it is only a warning.

Answer (score 0):

please vote for [WEB-55655](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55655) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: This really seems more like a comment.